# How do I change the volume of the sound or music in PyGame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, volume

How to change volume in PyGame like changing the volume by going to the settings. I made the UI elements, just need to know how to change the volume. I know I am not clear, but you can understand me. Please help

Comment: Please add more details--especially examples of code written, along with any error output you're seeing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changing the volume depends on whether you are playing a [`pygame.mixer.Sound`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound) object or playing the music via the [`pygame.mixer.music`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html) module.

The volume of a *Sound* can be changed by [`set_volume()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound.set_volume). The volume argument is a value in range [0.0, 1.0]:

```py
pygame.mixer.init()
my_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('my_sound.wav')
my_sound.play()

my_sound.set_volume(0.5)
```

The volume of the music can be changed by [`pygame.mixer.music.set_volume()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.set_volume):

```py
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load('my_music.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play()

pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.5)
```